# i have one Issue in My Query not get Group Record

Tags: asp.net, sql

hi i have one issue in get query like 3 column

```
ID       Grp      Name
1         10        aa
2         11        bb
3         11        cc 
4         11        dd
5         12        ee
6         12        ff
```

i want ans is

```
ID   Grp   Name
1     10    aa
2     11    bb
5     12    ee
```

so what can id Do ?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? `SQL Server` or `MySQL`?

Comment: What is `asp.net` doing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sql server

Try this !

```
select * from
(
select *,rn=row_number()over(partition by Grp order by ID) from table
)x
where x.rn=1
```

Comment: Thank you my Query Problem Is Solved

Answer (score 1):

For **SQL Server:**

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT *,RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Grp ORDER BY ID) 
             FROM TableName)
SELECT ID,Grp,Name 
FROM CTE
WHERE RN=1
```

Example in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f88db/1).

For **MySQL:**

```
SELECT ID,Grp,Name 
FROM
(SELECT A.ID, A.Grp, A.Name, count(*) as row_number FROM TableName A
JOIN TableName B ON A.Grp = B.Grp AND A.ID >= B.ID
GROUP BY A.Grp, A.ID,A.Name) T
WHERE row_number=1
```

Example in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05b7f/4).